# funroll loops option and tuning parameters in gcc

Tags: c, gcc

I am working on a benchmark written in C. I tried to compile it using optimization flag - funroll-loops present in gcc. I compile it with just funroll-loops and then funroll-loops --param max-unrolled-insns=10 and surprisingly it took 50 sec more for the binary which was compiled with funroll-loops --param max-unrolled-insns=10 option to run than the binary compiled with simply funroll-loops. 
The same case with funroll-all-loops too. 
I am unable to understand this behavior of gcc. Why does the performance degrade when we use the tuning parameter max-unrolled-insns?
Kindly help.

Comment: Some loops are best left rolled up.  That's why it isn't on by default; sometimes loop unrolling works better, and sometimes it does not.

Answer (score 1):

When you say it added 50 seconds, what is it in reference to, how big is the total number?

max-unrolled-insns will set the number of instructions a loop can unroll to, so if you set it to 10, there is a good chance you will lose some percent. For example.. if you have a loop that has 6 instructions, it won't unroll at all because unrolling would make it 12 instructions.

Not unrolling in this case would make you lose a few instructions and force a branch.. so it could add a few percent to the amount of time something takes to run.

Comment: The total number is somewhere aroung 750sec. okay so max-unroll-insns parameter would decide the max number of instructions it can unroll ? but to how many times of unrolling? i mean for the example you gave, it would be to unroll the loop once - which would generate 12 instructions so for max-unroll-insns=10, it wont be able to.